# Poor download speed after publishing shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have created an R shiny app to create some output. When I run it in local the app generates and downloads output instantaneously.
But when I publish it on a free R shiny server, it takes almost 20-30 mins to download the same file. The file size is 10MB.
Can you tell me the reasons for this?
Is there a work around ? Do I need to purchase a premium Rserver or something?

Comment: Are you publishing to `shinyapps.io` ([tag:shinyapps]), or to an instance of shiny-server that you have installed somewhere? ([tag:shiny-server]) While the two tags are not incompatible, they can suggest different issues. Ultimately, knowing nothing about the file or the internet connection is going to make this a lot of *speculation*. Have you run net-speed benchmarks on both your computer and where the shiny-server is installed? (Don't take their word for it, test it yourself, in both directions ... I think most ISPs these days still have asymmetric speeds.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no common measures between a desktop computer and a web server especially mutualized servers such as free offering from cloud servers. Your desktop computer is often far more powerfull (memory/cpu/network).

Beside this the download is handled by the internal web server of shiny (httpuv to name it). It is quite good but not as good as full blown web servers that are built for this (apache, nginx, ...)

Moreover R is mostly single threaded (that means it does one thing at a time). Handling a download and responding to the user through UI are separate tasks.